# La referencia de celda está fuera del intervalo

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo esta macro en google sheets que me toma un dato en una celda de una hoja, (programacion, d5) y me borra toda la fila que está asociada al dato digitado en otra hoja (bd1), por ejemplo.

En d5 de la hoja PROGRMACION digito el numero 43, ella va a la hoja BD1, busca en el rango c8 a c24 donde dice 43 y borra toda la fila, pero me sale que la referencia está por fuera del intervalo. En excel la macro me sale (el cód es dif) pero en GAS estoy frito.

Según google el error está en esta línea: `var cell = bd1Range.getCell(i, 0);`

```
var bd1Range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("BD1").getRange("C8:C24");
var programacionRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PROGRAMACION").getRange("D5");
var valueToMatch = programacionRange.getValue();

// Itera sobre las celdas del rango "bd1Range"
for (var i = 0; i < bd1Range.getNumRows(); i++) {
var cell = bd1Range.getCell(i, 0);
var cellValue = cell.getValue();

if (cellValue === valueToMatch) {
  cell.getEntireRow().delete();

}
}
```

Comment: El mensaje de fuera de rango se usa cuando estas buscando en una celda sin datos, las colmnas se cuentan desde 1.